# Moved azure resource has disappeared

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I just moved my WebApp from one subscription to another and now I can't find it in the azure portal.

However, I see that the web application still works. 
It has not been deleted.

It is not listed in the result of the call to `Get-AzureRmResource`.

Do you have an idea to diagnose this problem?

## Update

I found an error entry in the target Resource Group activity log:

```
"properties": {
    "statusCode": "Conflict",
    "statusMessage": "{\"error\":
    {\"code\":\"ResourceMoveFailed\",\"message\":...
```

**BUT** my resource is not, either, in my old resource group !!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are experiencing an issue with the synchronization as mentioned in the following discussion [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a7a0071b-5425-47cb-95ed-73cbc047ab15/azure-web-apps-missing-on-the-new-portal?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview), to fix this issue you may contact the support to perform a re-sync.

Let us know if you need further assistance on this issue.

Comment: I ended up signing a support plan. I am waiting for the resolution of the problem.

Comment: I experienced this bug as well. Resources disappeared from a subscription. However, I was still able to access resources using external tools (Using SSMS to connect to and interact with my missing database, hitting Web Apps via HTTP through a browser, etc). Microsoft was able to re-sync my account and the missing resources appeared in the portal once again. So my advice is to see if you can interact with the missing resources via external tools. If so, it's probably this bug and you need to ask Microsoft for a re-sync.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the operations you perform are scoped per subscription. For example, `Get-AzureRmResource` works against the currently selected subscription. You can run `Get-AzureRmSubscription` to view the subscriptions you have access to. You can then switch between subscriptions with something like this:

```
Set-AzureRmContext -SubscriptionName "Example Subscription Two"
```

In the portal, you can filter all the blades to show resources in one or more subscriptions.

[image: Subscription filter in Azure Portal]

As the image points out, if that doesn't work you can [switch directories](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/edit-directory-now-in-new-portal/).

Comment: I checked all my subscriptions

Comment: You've also checked your directories?

Answer (score 0):

Try Azure Resource Explorer for furthermore information on resources.
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-resource-explorer-a-new-tool-to-discover-the-azure-api/

Comment: My resource does not appear either

Comment: Please check here once https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-audit